# Is there anyway create relationship for filter criteria which has vocabularies( state, city and location)?

Tags: 8, views, taxonomy-terms

list of available Vocabularies in my content type.

- Country(Term: US)
- State (Terms: CA , CO, DE.. etc)
- City (Terms:Fremont, Irwin, Los Angeles, Monument etc..)
- Location(Terms: All loacations)

I'm trying to create a view for published content result which uses above vocabularies. I need to expose filters to the users where I added above vocabulary fields. How to create a relationship to select particular state->city-> location
(For ex: State(CA)->City(Fremont)->location(xxx-fremont))

Below is the example filter. Please help. Thank you!

[image]

Comment: Are the vocabularies independent of each other?  In other words, the City is not linked to State, and State is not linked to Country?  Because if they are not linked, you are going to have tons of problems like Washington the city in Indiana, Iowa, Maine, Connecticut, Georgia, etc....  Georgia the country and Georgia the state, and so on.

Comment: Anyway to do all locations, you need to do an OR filter for country/state/city OR location.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply! Yes vocabularies are independent.
How can I do OR filter? Can you please elaborate? Much appreciated!

Comment: "Views or filter", third result in Google.  Read about "Filter groups": https://drupalize.me/tutorial/overview-filter-criteria-views?p=3377

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the link. I have added OR condition to the views filter which didn't solve my issue. Right now vocabularies are independent. Can I add any relationship to vocabularies in views filters to show users only access  particular state->City->Location (for example:Filter options:  When User selects FL state, it should display Miami, Tampa under city dropdown. When User selects Miami city, then only miami location should display.)

Answer (score 0):

The **Relationship** option in Views tracks entity references, so to use that option, you have to create Entity References among your terms.  In taxonomy terms, the parent and grandparent are entity references.

Generally speaking, Views can only use a data structure that already exists in the database, or can be built from other structures in the database; it can't create a structure "out of thin air."

**One approach: Using parents and grandparents**

To use parents and grandparents, you would have to delete your current terms and re-structure them like this:

- Grandparent: Country
- Parent: State
- Child: City

You can do this by setting the parent when you create each term:

- Countries have no parent
- States have a country as parent
- Cities have a state as parent

Since there are no rules that enforce this structure unless you code the rules yourself, you have to be careful to make sure you set things correctly.

If you take this approach, you can add relationships to get the parent / grandparent under **Relationships** in Views, but making the filters by country / state / city will be a pain.

**Alternative approach that will make it easier to add the filters but that is harder to maintain**

Keep the vocabularies independent.  Add an entity reference field (term reference) to the **State** term type called **Country** and let users select a country.

Add two more entity reference fields (term reference) to the **City** term type called **State** and **Country**.

Then you have to set the correct country for each state, and state and country for each city.

Then, in your View, you can simply show a list of cities, and the filters for Country, State, and City will work for cities as you expect.

Note, however, that if a country or state has no cities, no entries will appear.  This is because we set this View to only show the list of cities to make setting up the filters easier.

Comment: I totally get what you mentioned here. But in my case, vocabularies should be independent and cannot add entity reference fields since they have used in other functionalities. I think we can customize the views exposed filters with javascript and ajax calls. I'm totally new to the Javascript. Can you please provide the sample javascript code for exposed views filters in this case?  Thanks you so much for your time. Greatly appreciated!

Comment: @NewDeep If you want someone to write code for you, hire a developer and pay them well .